# AadTokenProvider returns access token from old user

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

We are developing Microsoft Sharepoint "Widgets" using javascript(React) and aadTokenProviderFactory to acquire tokens.

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

const getMSToken = async (context: WebPartContext) => {
  const provider = await context.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
  const token = await provider.getToken('https://graph.microsoft.com');

  return token;
}
```

This token is valid and everything works fine. But when switching users I receive a token from the old user.
How to solve this issue and acquire tokens for the user that is currently signed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
getToken method has 2nd parameter called useCachedToken: boolean.

```
const token = await provider.getToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', false);
```